# R question - how to net transactions between entities

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I feel like this is an easy problem that I can't solve for some reason. Suppose I have a dataframe that lists trades between entities and I want to find the net amount for each pair. The dataframe might look like this:

| sending_entity | receiving_entity | amount_traded |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tim | Bob | 100 |
| Bob | Tim | 50 |
| Sarah | Jane | 25 |
| Jane | Sarah | 50 |

And the result I want is to know that Tim and Bob settled where Tim gave Bob a net amount of 50, and Jane gave Sarah a net amount of 25.

I thought about creating 2 sparse matrices, one for sending and one for receiving, and then subtracting the matrices. But this seems janky and would prefer a tidyverse way of doing this (or at least within the dataframe data structure), if possible.

Comment: Would your actual data have transactions between e.g. Bob and Jane? In other words, are transactions always grouped? Tim + Bob, Sarah + Jane, but never any cross transactions?

Comment: Yes there are some cross transactions. It was my attempt at a baby example. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a pair column that is built so that unique pairings have the same value, then used `xtabs`:

```
 dfrm$pair <- with( dfrm, paste( ifelse(sending_entity>receiving_entity,
                                          paste(receiving_entity,sending_entity),
                                          paste(sending_entity, receiving_entity) ))
                                )
 dfrm
#-------------
  sending_entity receiving_entity amount_traded       pair
1            Tim              Bob           100    Bob Tim
2            Bob              Tim            50    Bob Tim
3          Sarah             Jane            25 Jane Sarah
4           Jane            Sarah            50 Jane Sarah
#--------------

xtabs(amount_traded~pair, dfrm)
#--------------
pair
   Bob Tim Jane Sarah 
       150         75
```